# Get style of text from Gedit plugin

Tags: gtk, gedit, gedit-plugin

I'm working on a plugin for the text editor Gedit written in Python where I need to know the formatting (color etc.) of a specific character in the text of a `Gtk.Document`. I have tried to call `get_attibutes()` on a `Gtk.TextIter` object but I cannot get anything out of the resulting `Gtk.TextAttributes` object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome text editor uses **Gtk.SourceView** as a base, and **Gtk.SourceView** has as one of its features the possibility of applying a predetermined style based on the syntax of the language used in the file (the focus is programming). This is done through **Gtk.Tags**, to get the tags that apply to a certain **Gtk.TextIter** you have to use `Gtk.TextIter.get_tags()`.